# How to deploy web template after saving it using powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, sharepoint-on-prem

I am able to save a web template using this code,

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell –ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$Web=Get-SPWeb http://globas/

$Web.SaveAsTemplate("test4","test4","test4",0)
```

Now I want to do following,

- I want to deploy this saved template to all web applications using Deploy solution... I am not sure if I need to download it first and then update-solution or if there is any shortcut...

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/34dfad4a-2291-4b58-b529-206c5731eedf/how-to-save-a-site-template-to-farm-and-deploy-it-to-new-site?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: @Christoffer thanks but this article and then the article referenced within it are not helpful, they define stuff I already know but nothing concrete to help me specifically

Comment: I think the answer in the article were exactly what you were asking about. You have saved a site as a template in a wsp solution. Now you wonder would like to deploy the solution/template to all your sites in all your web applications which would require that you either add it to a farm-scoped visual studio solution, or write some PowerShell to loop through all sites in your web applications and deploy the wsp solution as a sandbox solution using add-spusersolution then activate it in all sites (as it's site-scoped).

Comment: @Christoffer I already know this, but I am not sure how to do it in powershell or code, that's what I am asking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrote some quick code that should give you a start. You need to run this as a site collection administrator.

First, add the path to your WSP solution in the variable $Path.

Then if you would like to exclude some webapplications, like the mysite webapplication as an example, add the full URL instead of webAppURL1, webAppURL2.

Then loop through all the sites in the web applications and add the solution as a sandbox solution then activate it. I'm a little bit unsure if the pause (sleep) with 10 seconds while be enough to add the solution before activating it so you might need to see if you can solve that somehow to make sure that the solution is added before trying to activate/install it.

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#example: $path = "c:\progam\myWebtemplateSolution.wsp"
$path = ""

$excludeWebApp = @("webAppURL1",
                   "webAppURL2",
                   "webAppURL3")

$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication | Where {$_.Url -notin $excludeWebApp}

foreach ($site in $webapp.sites) 

{
    Add-SPUserSolution -LiteralPath $path -Site $site
    Start-Sleep -s 10
    Install-SPUserSolution -Identity myWebtemplateSolution.wsp -Site $site
}
```

**Note that i have not tested the code and it might not work/need some tinkering.**